# Xcode 6 randomly changing storyboards to size wAny hAny?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6

I'm working on a project that supports iOS 7 and 8. The storyboard was initially created in Xcode 5. We updated to Xcode 6 and have started using size classes.

However, we're iPhone only right now, so we're laying things out in wCompact hRegular. Problem is, **Xcode randomly wants to revert our storyboards to wAny hAny**. It's driving me absolutely insane. Is there a setting or something I'm not seeing to disable this behavior?

Comment: I've never seen that behavior, but definitely file a bug report at bugreport.apple.com - that's not expected behavior. Also try Xcode 6.1.1 GM build and 6.2 beta to see if they've already resolved that bug, they may already have known about it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally we hate Size Classes and Auto Layout, because sometimes those functions really drive us crazy, so, since your project is for iPhone, disable size classes and use traditional autoresizing in the Inspector panel of XCode, plus some manual setup into viewDidLoad (if it's necessary), using UIScreen, like this:

```
if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) {
   //iPhone 5

} else if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480) {
   //iPhone 4

} else if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width == 375) {
   //iPhone 6

} else if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width == 414) {
   //iPhone 6+

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a really really terrible idea. One should never use magic numbers.

Comment: Well, we use that code all the times, so we make sure that all Views will stay were we want :)

Comment: If you absolutely must do that, and sometimes you do but that should be rare, at least use a range of numbers, and include an `else` statement, instead of fixing it to a single size. When a new screen size is released you're in trouble if you use this code as-is. For example, if `width < 420`. Also it's not wise to test against `height` and `width` inconsistently.